# when to use the future tense and not the subjunctive

Tags: subjuntivo, futuro

For a piece of homework I had to write a short essay.

I wrote the line below and when I was going through it with my teacher I thought she would say it was incorrect. The reason I thought it was incorrect was because I was talking about my opinion so thought I should have used the subjunctive.

> Creo que acelerará el uso de más tecnología remota

My teacher did explain why it was correct to use the future tense in this case however being old I have forgotten the reason which is rather annoying.

Why is the subjunctive not used here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use the indicative to express opinions, as long as the opinion verb is in positive form:

> Creo que acelerará.
>
> Creo que viene.
>
> Creo que va a venir.

Or even (as the opinion verb is still in positive form):

> Creo que no acelerará.
>
> Creo que no viene.
>
> Creo que no va a venir.

We use the subjunctive to express opinions in negative form:

> No creo que acelere. / No creo que vaya a acelerar.
>
> No creo que venga.
>
> No creo que vaya a venir.